# Excel doesn't work in asp.net when deployed in IIS

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis

I'm having problem integrating the excel into my asp.net application deployed in IIS. In localhost it works properly but when I deployed it in IIS it returns an error "Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class".

I already configured the DCOM Config Security permissions by adding Network Service and IIS in launch and activation and access permissions. I also set 'NetworkService' as Identity in IIS Application Pools but the error still persist.

How can I resolve this? Do I need additional configuration in IIS or component services?

Comment: If you are using Interop, then don't. It will cause more trouble than it will solve. There is a reason it does not work on the server.

Comment: @VDWWD yes I'm using Interop. Is there an alternative for Interop? and What should be the reason if it does not work on the server?

Comment: Depends on what you are using Interop for. But Excel is not meant to be used in website hosting environments.

Comment: I'm using excel to automatically write data on it and also to retrieve data from it. Should I better use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 than Interop?

Comment: Yep, or use a specialized library like EPPlus to read and write excel documents.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your suggestions @VDWWD